# Freeze layers using Tensorflow Object Detection API

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, computer-vision, object-detection, object-detection-api

Is it possible to freeze specific layers when using Tensorflow Object Detection API?

For example, I am using EfficientDet downloaded from the Tensorflow 2 Model Zoo.
When I train the model, I am going to make it predict whether an object is car,plane or motorcycle. The model is already trained on these types of objects (COCO 2017 dataset), but I want to train it more on my specific use case . But, since it is already trained on these types of object I do not want it to "forget" what it has already learned. Hence, I need to freeze some of the layers. So, is this possible? And, if it is possible, how do I know which layers I actually need to freeze?

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, It is possible to freeze layers in your model

You can freeze all the layers by

```
For layer in model.layers:
    layer.trainable = False
```

Or you can freeze individual layers by

```
model.layers[-1].trainable = False # Freeze the last layer
model.layers[-2].trainable = False # Freeze the second-last layer
```

Or you can freeze using a loop

```
for x in range(2,6):
    model.layers[x].trainable = False
```

Comment: As far as I can see it is not possible to iterate the layers of the models from Tensorflow Model Zoo since they are not keras models?

Answer (score 0):

yes , It is possible , here is  a way to freeze the lase layer in model using tf2.

I assume you are working on object detection API and you run this file to train the model

> model_main_tf2.py

so if that so , you go to the file in the same directory with this name

> model_lib_v2.py

and then go to line showing in the image implemented and add this line

```
detection_model.feature_extractor.trainable = False
```

before this line

```
  summary_writer_filepath = get_filepath(strategy,
                                         os.path.join(model_dir, 'train'))
```

and that's it you are done :)

note :
you can use [netron](https://netron.app/) to know what layer freezed

[image: ROW IN RED LINE]